# Airflow BigQueryGetDataOperator max_results parameter doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api, airflow

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.utils import dates
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_get_data import BigQueryGetDataOperator




default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='bigQueryPipeline',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *'
)


t1 = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='bigquery_test',
    dataset_id= <my-dataset-name>,
    table_id= <my-table-id>,
    max_results='2',
)


def print_context(**context):
    import time
    import json
    xcom_pull = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='bigquery_test')
    logging.info('logging ', json.dumps(xcom_pull))


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_result',
    python_callable=print_context,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

t1 >> t2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

So, this is my DAG. I'm testing getting data from a BigQuery table. Everything works except for the max_results argument, which is in the [docs](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_get_data/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_get_data.BigQueryGetDataOperator).

As I can see in the logs:

```
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,272] {bigquery_get_data.py:92} INFO - Fetching Data from:
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,272] {bigquery_get_data.py:94} INFO - Dataset: <my-dataset> ; Table: <my-table> ; Max Results: 2
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,291] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2019-11-26 14:46:02,291] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:145} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,309] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2019-11-26 14:46:02,309] {discovery.py:271} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,412] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2019-11-26 14:46:02,412] {discovery.py:867} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<my-project>/datasets/<my-dataset>tables/<my-table>/data?maxResults=2&alt=json
[2019-11-26 14:46:02,851] {bigquery_get_data.py:106} INFO - Total Extracted rows: 77374
```

Notice the `Max Results: 2` in the 2nd line, and the `?maxResults=2` querystring in the 5th line. Besides that, `Total Extracted rows: 77374` in the last line.

I'm guessing maybe it's a bigquery api bug?

Do any of you guys know how can I report this to Airflow? And to Google?

**edit**: found where to [submit bug reports for airflow](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/).

Answer (score 0):

You should give "max_results" parameter as an integer. I see in your code that it is string (max_results='2'). Check the below documentation please.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_get_data/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a Bigquery error, the result you are seeing is the result of all the data processed by the instruction **BigQueryGetDataOperator**.

Therefore, if you want to see the result of the second step *t2*, you should look for a completed task (dark green).

[image]

Now, click over your **Task Id** "*print_result*" of your Dag.

[image]

This way you will be able to see the logs of this step with the result.

In addition, you can check the result of the first step selecting one completed task, like in the previous step, but this time with **Task Id** "*bigquery_test*".

[image]

Then, click on the "*XCom*" button, and here you will see the two results returned.

Here are the result from my test:

processed rows:

[image]

results:

[image]